# Kusto Query Percentage Calculation showing incorrect data

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have the following kusto query to find out som differece in 2 columns:

```
customEvents
| where name == "Nulls"
| project timestamp,    
    Column = tostring(customDimensions["Column"]),
    CurrentNull = toint(customDimensions["CurrentNull"]),
    PreviousNull = toint(customDimensions["PreviousNull"]),
    CurrentRows = toint(customDimensions["CurrentRows"]),
    PreviousRows = toint(customDimensions["PreviousRows"])    
| distinct timestamp, Column, CurrentNull, PreviousNull, CurrentRows, PreviousRows
| extend Delta = CurrentNull - PreviousNull,
         CurrentNullPercent = (CurrentNull/CurrentRows) * 100,
         PreviousNullPercent = (PreviousNull/PreviousRows) * 100
| distinct timestamp, Column, CurrentNull, PreviousNull, Delta, CurrentNullPercent, CurrentRows
| order by Delta desc
```

[image]

I notice that the CurrentNullPercent value is not correct. For example, 12,517/352393 * 100 should be 3 and it is displayed as 0. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Integer arithmetic](https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/integer-arithmetic#:%7E:text=Arithmetic%20without%20fractions.,yield%20the%20whole%20number%202.)

> Arithmetic without fractions. A computer performing integer arithmetic
> ignores any fractions that are derived. For example, 8 divided by 3
> would yield the whole number 2.

Use

```
(1.0 * CurrentNull / CurrentRows) * 100
```

Or

```
(toreal(CurrentNull) / CurrentRows) * 100
```